# rescue grub not working

Tags: grub2

So in the middle of formating one of my drivers battery died and after starting the laptop i got rescue grub . i tried all the hd partions with ls and none of them has the boot/grub in them. Using ls i am not getting all my partitions btw it is showing 3 while i have 5. After number of attemps with rescue grub i tried installing a new ubuntu and i got a menu suggesting memory test and disk defect test . I tried disk defect test option and  i get this error:
/script/init-top/framebuffer: line 125 cant fork
/init: /scrpt/init-top/order:line 13 cant fork
kernel panic - not syncing attemted to kill init exitcode=some number
cpu:0 pid: 1 comm: init not tainted 3.19.0 - 25-generic some number again
hardware name : my laptops model and its bios model
call trace : weird stuff
kernel offset: some number(relocation range) some number
drm_kms_helper: panic occured, switching back to text console
i am stuck in this page and i am on my phone sry about spelling errors

Comment: I was able to boot up my PC with an earlier version of ubuntu  . I used 10.04.3 LTS. I lost my data but got my laptop back Fair exchange i guess

Answer (score 2):

Try with "boot-repair".

Boot from a live-cd/usb, and run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

I found it in:
https://askubuntu.com/a/182863/287964

More information:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: i will try it after work

Comment: it did not work same error ; kernel panic :(